# How to handle big array of objects in js client

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, xmlhttprequest, bigdata

Inside an admin panel i need to fetch 50000 of objects (and it grows) and  show them on the map (using leaflet)
The objects contains only lat and lng and i am using clusters right now to make it visually better and more performant l, it take too much ram thou and i know it is not the best practice and i was unable to make it better.
Is there any way to handle it safely?
I can cache the data in the browser but i do not have any idea about where to store it (maybe the inbuilt DB?)

Thanks in advance...

I currently just storing it inside a variable but each time dashboard is opening the request is sent again and fetching th data again (i thing it is about 10MB of data)

Found a stack overflow question but the size and count of data is too much low in his question for my situation

I know i can use service workers but i don't know where it will affect (considering using it right now)

UPDATE 1: my main problem is the Map, it has 50,000 markers on it and it will increase in a short time (and for some reasons i need to show all of them - i am and will use clustering). my main concern is usage of ram and CPU (when doing operations on them), if you had a similar problem how you resolved it?

Comment: If it's always the same data being fetched, the browser cache should suffice, no? As long as your response headers are set properly.

Comment: It may get changed (the api fetches the list of locations of the customers) so it may be a change of status or location or add and delete the data that is done on the server

Comment: I would consider either using IndexedDB or change the api to deliver chunks on demand (I doubt you need all data at the start)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev see UPDATE 1

Comment: @SinaVali you could try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache to cache your data

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev i read the doc, it is efficient but too hard to use i may go with indexed db or localstorage. NOW as i said the main problem is the operation that i need to perform on this data (mainly map and filter) as i did not worked with this amount of data i know it would be like an endless loop just to do a map